# How to get a left aligned equation?

Tags: align

With the code

```
\begin{eqnarray}
\Bra{\psi(0)}b_n^+b_n\Ket{\psi(0)} = \nonumber\\
\Bra{\psi_0}(\sum_l U^l_n a_l^+(t) + V^l_n a_l(t))(\sum_m U_n^m a_m(t) + V_n^m a_m^+(t))\Ket{\psi_0}
\end{eqnarray}
```

or

```
\begin{align}
\Bra{\psi(0)}b_n^+b_n\Ket{\psi(0)} = \nonumber\\
\Bra{\psi_0}(\sum_l U^l_n a_l^+(t) + V^l_n a_l(t))(\sum_m U_n^m a_m(t) + V_n^m a_m^+(t))\Ket{\psi_0}
\end{align}
```

or

```
\begin{flalign}
\Bra{\psi(0)}b_n^+b_n\Ket{\psi(0)} = \nonumber\\
\Bra{\psi_0}(\sum_l U^l_n a_l^+(t) + V^l_n a_l(t))(\sum_m U_n^m a_m(t) + V_n^m a_m^+(t))\Ket{\psi_0}
\end{flalign}
```

I get the same output:

[image]

With the code:

```
\begin{gather}
\Bra{\psi(0)}b_n^+b_n\Ket{\psi(0)} = \nonumber\\
\Bra{\psi_0}(\sum_l U^l_n a_l^+(t) + V^l_n a_l(t))(\sum_m U_n^m a_m(t) + V_n^m a_m^+(t))\Ket{\psi_0}
\end{gather}
```

I get:

[image]

With the code,

```
\begin{multline}
\Bra{\psi(0)}b_n^+b_n\Ket{\psi(0)} = \\
\Bra{\psi_0}(\sum_l U^l_n a_l^+(t) + V^l_n a_l(t))(\sum_m U_n^m a_m(t) + V_n^m a_m^+(t))\Ket{\psi_0}
\end{multline}
```

I get:

[image]

But what I want is (image edited with paint):

[image]

Can someone help me to get that?. Thanks.

Comment: (1) Welcome, (2) on this site we prefer full minimal examples, not sniplet like this where we have to add code in order for us to test your code. (3) In the `align` based constructions you need to specify an alignment point using `&`, (4) in general you'd break the line before `=` not after, if `=` or say `+` ends the like it is easily overlooked.

Answer (score 3):

You just have to add a pair of `&`s to the `flalign` environment:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath, braket}
\usepackage[showframe]{geometry} 

\begin{document}

\begin{flalign}
 & \Bra{\psi(0)}b_n^+b_n\Ket{\psi(0)} = & \nonumber\\
 & \Bra{\psi_0}(\sum_l U^l_n a_l^+(t) + V^l_n a_l(t))(\sum_m U_n^m a_m(t) + V_n^m a_m^+(t))\Ket{\psi_0}
\end{flalign}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: That works perfect!!, Thanks a lot by your quick answer :)

Answer (score 1):

You need `&` in front of the two parts; I also suggest using `\Braket`, although the delimiters seem a bit too big.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,braket}

\begin{document}

\begin{align}
&\Bra{\psi(0)}b_n^+b_n\Ket{\psi(0)} = \nonumber\\
&\Bra{\psi_0}(\sum_l U^l_n a_l^+(t) + V^l_n a_l(t))(\sum_m U_n^m a_m(t) + V_n^m a_m^+(t))\Ket{\psi_0}
\end{align}

\begin{align}
&\Braket{\psi(0) | b_n^+b_n | \psi(0)} = \nonumber\\
&\Braket{\psi_0 | \Bigl(\sum_{\smash{l}} U^l_n a_l^+(t) + V^l_n a_l(t)\Bigr)
                  \Bigl(\sum_{\smash{m}} U_n^m a_m(t) + V_n^m a_m^+(t)\Bigr)
                | \psi_0}
\end{align}

\end{document}
```

[image]

A different strategy is using `split`, that will center the equation number (but will honor the `tbtags` option to `amsmath`).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,braket}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
&\Bra{\psi(0)}b_n^+b_n\Ket{\psi(0)} = \\
&\Bra{\psi_0}(\sum_l U^l_n a_l^+(t) + V^l_n a_l(t))(\sum_m U_n^m a_m(t) + V_n^m a_m^+(t))\Ket{\psi_0}
\end{split}
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
&\Braket{\psi(0) | b_n^+b_n | \psi(0)} =\\
&\Braket{\psi_0 | \Bigl(\sum_{l} U^l_n a_l^+(t) + V^l_n a_l(t)\Bigr)
                  \Bigl(\sum_{m} U_n^m a_m(t) + V_n^m a_m^+(t)\Bigr)
                | \psi_0}
\end{split}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

[image]